# getting Google returned a response with code 400 error in pytrend

Tags: python, google-trends

I want to get yesterday or todays data from pytrend but every time i use this code i keep getting
`The request failed: Google returned a response with code 400.`
with the data
and sometimes timeout or rate limit exceed error

my code

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()
kw_list = ['pizza']
data =  pytrend.get_historical_interest(kw_list, 
                                year_start=2021,
                                month_start=12,
                                day_start=28,
                                hour_start=0,
                                
                                year_end=2021,
                                month_end=12,
                                day_end=28,
                                hour_end=23)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq()
kw_list = ['pizza']
data = pytrend.get_historical_interest(kw_list,
                                       year_start=2021,
                                       month_start=12,
                                       day_start=28,
                                       hour_start=0,

                                       year_end=2021,
                                       month_end=12,
                                       day_end=28,
                                       hour_end=23,

                                       sleep=60)  # Delay added for rate limit
print(data)
```

**pytrends**

> **sleep**
>
> If you are rate-limited by Google, you should set this parameter to
> something (i.e. 60) to space off each API call.

https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/

> if you want to use proxies as you are blocked due to Google rate limit

**Google Trends API rate limit**

> By default, it is set to 100 requests per 100 seconds per user and can
> be adjusted to a maximum value of 1,000. But the number of requests to
> the API is restricted to a maximum of 10 requests per second per user.

Comment: getting this error ```requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='trends.google.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)``` also the error is not fixed still getting ```The request failed: Google returned a response with code 400.```